# OpenLayers's CSS breaks after publishing to Azure Web Site

Tags: azure, openlayers

I've created a very simple ASP.NET 4.5 MVC4 web site which uses OpenLayers 2.12. It's got only one page that shows a map with a few points and lines on it. If I run it locally, it runs fine, but after publishing to my Azure Web Site, the OpenLayers' CSS files won't load. I have now added the OpenLayers CSS hard coded in my bundleConfig, and now it works fine. But of course, this is not what I want, because OpenLayers has specific CSS files for other platforms and browser versions etc.

Locally, I just have to include openlayers.js and OpenLayers then adds the right css files. Does anybody know why this doesn't work after publishing to Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs in openlayers.js:

```
Please remember that when your OpenLayers script is not named
"OpenLayers.js" you will have to make sure that the default theme is
loaded into the page by including an appropriate <link>-tag,
e.g.:

(code)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/default/style.css" type="text/css">
(end code)
```

Because Azure changes the file names that are included, I indeed should be adding the reference to the default style myself. Also, I can just link to style.css, the other css files for e.g. IE6 or Mobile won't be uses automatically, these are just there for yourself to use it when appropriate.